# JMeter - some CSV rows ignore config and contain unexpected data

Tags: csv, jmeter

I'm using Taurus 1.12 (with its embedded JMeter 4.0), running on a Docker container in TeamCity (AWS hosted).

I'm running a fairly low intensity test - 10 concurrency, 6 requests per user, throughput capped at 10 - and I'm encountering strange values in the CSV which break the plugins to generate graphs.

[image]

As you can see, the "success" column contains a strange "text" value, and all the following values are shifted by one. The plugins throw an exception since the "bytes" value is empty.

In the last run (10h30m long) there were 6 occurrences of these lines, in a CSV with about 330k lines.

I noticed that all the occurrences seem to be duplicates of the previous request - same endpoint and elapsed values. The hostname is "0" for some reason...

Suspecting some CSV delimiter issues caused by threadName values, I tried removeding the threadName column altogether from the Results Tree Config, but the new result is even stranger:

[image]

The threadName value has appeared from nowhere, in addition to "text".

Interestingly, Taurus' kpi.log doesn't contain these silly rows at all.
For instance, in relation to the second picture, the corresponding kpi contains:

```
1529955107932,9,Add quote to basket,200,OK,Create Enquiry through to select quote 1-2,true,162,10,10,9,e4ad73a192d4,0
1529955107932,10,Add quote to basket,200,OK,Create Enquiry through to select quote 1-5,true,162,10,10,10,e4ad73a192d4,0
1529955107932,10,Create new basket,201,Created,Create Enquiry through to select quote 1-9,true,224,10,10,10,e4ad73a192d4,1
1529955108268,4,Get basket,200,OK,Create Enquiry through to select quote 1-1,true,839,10,10,4,e4ad73a192d4,0
1529955108268,4,Get basket,200,OK,Create Enquiry through to select quote 1-3,true,1092,10,10,4,e4ad73a192d4,0
1529955108269,4,Get basket,200,OK,Create Enquiry through to select quote 1-10,true,1086,10,10,4,e4ad73a192d4,0
```

I ran the same 10.5h test again with the changes:

- Re-enabled threadName
- Enabled dataType

The graphs were not cut this time, but some contained dodgy data points: threadCount was reported at very high values, between 100 and 297, in 3 occasions.

Again, I found 3 dodgy lines corresponding to those values - this time, though, the data format is correct, so the plugins do not explode due to empty values.

[image]

These data points screw up some of the graphs...

[image]

Does anybody have a clue about it?
Thx

Comment: something is adding those values... do you have pre-post processor, or any other visualizer, or maybe some scripting object? Strip out anything other than requests and see if it still happens.